# JqueryUI sortable: el thead y tbody se encogen al arrastrar una fila con dos campos con display none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tengo una tabla con diferentes filas y campos, en una fila tengo dos campos con `display:none;` y al hacer un drag de esta fila, hay un efecto como de padding lateral en el `<tbody>`y en el `<thead>`, la tabla no se encoge, lo que se encoge son estos elementos.

En el JsFiddle que dejo a continuación, en la primera fila pasa lo comentado anteriormente, en cambio en la segunda que solo hay un elemento con `display:none;`no pasa.

https://jsfiddle.net/w52m5ggb/20/

Ante cualquier duda preguntar, llevo bastante tiempo con esto.

Al principio pensaba que se podría solucionar buscando la cantidad de elementos `<td>`con la clase `.hidden-td`(clase que tiene un `display:none;`) y buscar el elemento con la clase `.placeholder-style`(es la clase que tiene el `<tr>`que se genera al hacer el drag) y añadirle tantos `<td>`como hay en el `<tr>`que estoy moviendo, pero no (posiblemente, también esta mal planteado).

Comment: Eso pasa porque tu primer fila tiene 9 elementos, mientras tus demás filas tienen 8, y en tu función `start()` sólo ocultas una columna en tu placeholder, entonces al hacer drag a la primer fila, queda una columna en tu placeholder sin aplicar la clase `hidden-td` y por eso queda ese espacio al final de tus columnas. ¿Qué tan seguido es que tu tabla tenga elementos ocultos y que no sea la misma cantidad entre filas?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Yikarus bien explicado y bien entendido por mi parte, en el código real a veces hay 8 columnas en la fila, se reduce y varias se ponen en `display:none;`, luego alomejor vuelve a aparecer una; con lo cual se tendría que hacer de manera dinámica, que en cada momento sepa cuantos elementos están `hidden` y haga el drag correctamente en cada momento.

Comment: Esto lo podríamos hacer con la siguiente línea de código: `var numcells = $('.hidden-td').length;` @Yikarus alguna idea de como seguir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He dado solución a tu problema haciendo lo siguiente:

La lógica que implemente es simple, hay n cantidad de columnas visibles en la tabla, la idea es saber exactamente cuantas hay y comparar con la cantidad de columnas que tiene cada `<tr>`, después por medio del selector `:nth-child()` seleccionamos la cantidad de columnas sobrantes y le asignamos la clase `.hidden-td`

```js
$("#tabs").tabs();

$("#tbodyproject").sortable({
    items: "> tr",
    appendTo: "parent",
    helper: "clone",
    placeholder: "placeholder-style",
    start: function(event, ui) {
    
    var cantidad_real = $('.table thead tr th:visible').length;
      var cantidad_actual = $(this).find('.placeholder-style td').length;
        
     if(cantidad_actual > cantidad_real){
        var cantidad_a_ocultar = (cantidad_actual - cantidad_real);
        
        for(var i = 0; i <= cantidad_a_ocultar; i++){
            $(this).find('.placeholder-style td:nth-child('+ i +')').addClass('hidden-td');
        }
      }
      
      ui.helper.css('display', 'block');
      ui.helper.css('width', '100% !important');
     
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.css('display', '')
    },
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        let newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'/admin/projects/updateOrder',
            data: {ids: newOrder}
        })
       .done(function( msg ) {
        location.reload();        
       });
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}
.hidden-td{
  display:none !important;
}
.table{
  background-color:green;
  border:0;
}
.trdrag{
  background-color:yellow;
}
.thcenter{
  background-color:grey !important;
}
.ui-sortable-helper {
  left:0px!important;
}
.idrow{
  width:5%;
}
.tdvisible{
  width:5%;
}
.tdslug{
  width:10%;
}
.tdimg{
  width:15%;
}
.tdorder{
  width:20%;
}
.tdacciones{
  width:40%;
}

@media (max-width: 500px){
  .ocultarid{
    display:none;
  }
  .tdslug{
    width:15%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="tabs">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="table1">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="thcenter ocultarid">ID</th>
                    <th class="thcenter">Visible</th>
                    <th class="thcenter">Nombre</th>
                    <th class="thcenter">Header</th>
                    <th class="thcenter">Home</th>
                    <th class="thcenter">Orden</th>
                    <th class="thcenter"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Acciones</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbodyproject"> 
                    <tr id="id1" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter ocultarid"><p id="margindata">1</p></td>
                      <td  class="hidden-td" style="display:none;">Testing</td>
                      <td  class="hidden-td" style="display:none;">Testing2</td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdvisible"> 
                        Yes
                      </td>
                      <td class="tdslug"><p id="margindata">Slug</p></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdorder"><p id="margindata">Order 1</p></td>
                      <td class="tdacciones">
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 1">Delete
                      </form>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr id="id1" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter ocultarid"><p id="margindata">2</p></td>
                      <td style="display:none;">Testing</td>
                      <td style="display:none;">Testing</td>
                      <td style="display:none;">Testing</td>
                      <td style="display:none;">Testing</td>
                      <td style="display:none;">Testing</td>
                      <td style="display:none;">Testing</td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdvisible"> 
                        Yes
                      </td>
                      <td class="tdslug"><p id="margindata">Slug</p></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdorder"><p id="margindata">Order 1</p></td>
                      <td class="tdacciones">
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 1">Delete
                      </form>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr id="id1" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter ocultarid"><p id="margindata">3</p></td>
                      <td style="display:none;">Testing</td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdvisible"> 
                        Yes
                      </td>
                      <td class="tdslug"><p id="margindata">Slug</p></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdorder"><p id="margindata">Order 1</p></td>
                      <td class="tdacciones">
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 1">Delete
                      </form>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr id="id1" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter ocultarid"><p id="margindata">1</p></td>
                      <td style="display:none;">Testing</td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdvisible"> 
                        Yes
                      </td>
                      <td class="tdslug"><p id="margindata">Slug</p></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdorder"><p id="margindata">Order 1</p></td>
                      <td class="tdacciones">
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 1">Delete
                      </form>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr id="id1" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter ocultarid"><p id="margindata">4</p></td>
                      <td style="display:none;">Testing</td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdvisible"> 
                        Yes
                      </td>
                      <td class="tdslug"><p id="margindata">Slug</p></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdorder"><p id="margindata">Order 1</p></td>
                      <td class="tdacciones">
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 1">Delete
                      </form>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="id2" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter ocultarid"><p id="margindata">5</p></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdvisible"> 
                        Yes
                      </td>
                      <td class="tdslug"><p id="margindata">Slug</p></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdorder"><p id="margindata">Order 2</p></td>
                      <td class="tdacciones">
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">

                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 2">Delete
                      </form>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Camilo, pero hay un problema y es que algunas veces hay 2 campos, otras 3, otras 1, de manera que habría que hacerlo dinámico, encontrando primero cuantos campos hidden hay y a partir de ahí añadir la clase hidden, estoy en ello.

Comment: Hola @LluísPuigFerrer, ya te he editado la respuesta con la forma dinámica.

Comment: lo veo bastante lioso, funcionar funciona, pero lo veo además 'limitado'. Te dejo este JsFiddle con cambios en el `CSS` como tengo en el código real, si pruebas a hacer pequeña la pantalla veras que vuelvo a tener el problema porque he ocultado otras columnas. https://jsfiddle.net/3g3bt80e/3/

Comment: Pero veo que sigues usando la opción estática y no la dinámica que te coloqué en la edición a la respuesta

Comment: Perdona, es que estoy probando varias maneras y se me olvido ponerlo! Aquí tienes https://jsfiddle.net/3g3bt80e/4/

Comment: Exactamente cual fila es la que no te funciona ? veo todo bien

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69015/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-camilo-vasquez).

Answer (score -1):

Es la solución mas rápida que he encontrado, espero que te sirva.

La idea es añadir en el `sortable` en la `start function` lo siguiente:

```
start:function(event, ui) {
  var hidden = ui.helper.find('td').map(function(i,el){
    if(this.style.display == 'none' || $(this).hasClass('hidden-td'))
        return this;
  }).length;

  if(hidden > 0){
    ui.placeholder.find('td').each(function(i,e){
      if(i<hidden)
          $(this).remove();
    });
  }
  ui.helper.css('display', 'table')
}
```

El javascript quedaría así por si quieres copiarlo entero:

```
$("#tabs").tabs();

$("#tbodyproject").sortable({
    items: "> tr",
    appendTo: "parent",
    helper: "clone",
    placeholder: "placeholder-style",
    start:function(event, ui) {
      var hidden = ui.helper.find('td').map(function(i,el){
        if(this.style.display == 'none' || $(this).hasClass('hidden-td'))
            return this;
      }).length;

      if(hidden > 0){
        ui.placeholder.find('td').each(function(i,e){
          if(i<hidden)
              $(this).remove();
        });
      }
      ui.helper.css('display', 'table')
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.css('display', '')
    },
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        let newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'/admin/projects/updateOrder',
            data: {ids: newOrder}
        })
       .done(function( msg ) {
        location.reload();        
       });
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Este seria el jsfiddle donde funciona: https://jsfiddle.net/maxik_95/Lge4bgey/2/

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Marc, es recomendable que al adjuntar una respuesta si puedes, pongas o todo el código o dejes en enlace a un JsFiddle, estoy probando tu código y no me funciona correctamente, si puedes déjame un JsFiddle para contrastar

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer he comprovado el codigo y si que fallaba un poco, lo he arreglado y te he añadido el link de jsfiddle, por si acaso te dejo el link aqui tambien: https://jsfiddle.net/maxik_95/Lge4bgey/2/

Comment: Este sábado probare el código, gracias!